# Firebird. Unique. Constraint vs index

Tags: sql, firebird

В Firebird 2.5 автоматический контроль уникальности подмножества столбцов можно осуществить двумя разными способами. Через ограничение и через уникальный индекс. Ограничение же всегда реализуется с помощью индекса.

Вопрос в следующем: Когда необходимо именно ограничение?

В [Firebird 2.5 Language Reference](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-ddl-idx.html) ограничились лишь одной фразой:

> A unique index is not a constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Ограничение проверяется сразу до вставки данных в таблицу. Поэтому срабатывает быстрее, чем просто использование уникального индекса

Answer (score 0):

Если рассматтривать логический результат, то разницы нет. Ограничение будет видно в каталоге ограничений, индекс - нет. Если нужен только индекс - создайте индекс.